# FFmpeg add #EXT-X-START to HLS m3u8 file

Tags: html, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am creating a HLS live streaming event playlist (m3u8 file and the ts segments) via FFmpeg. The segments at the beginning must not be removed from the playlist (it should contain all the segments). The HTML5 video element should start playing the video at the **very beginning** (by default it starts somewhere in the middle if the playlist contains several segments and the end tag is not contained at the end of the playlist file). To achieve that the video starts playing at the very beginning I need to add `#EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=0` to the playlist file. 
Currently my FFmpeg command is the following: 
`ffmpeg -i videoSrc -map 0 -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_playlist_type event -hls_allow_cache 0 -hls_segment_filename testSegmented%03d.ts testSegmentedHls.m3u8`. 
So my question is: How do I add `#EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=0` to my HLS m3u8 playlist file using FFmpeg?

Comment: Not implemented, feel free to add it.

Comment: Surprising, but neither [RFC 8216](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216) nor [HLS 2nd Ed (draft)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis) nor [HLS Authoring Spec for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/http_live_streaming_hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices) seem to define the (default?) playback starting position when `#EXT-X-START` is _NOT_ present. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aergistal mentioned in his comment, it's not implemented (yet?). I am now using this patch: https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/patch/522/